# Worksheet event in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a macro tool for our warehouse and I need some suggestions as I'm very new to VBA. There is macro tool where user will scan the barcode in the worksheet and scanned items has to be searched in range of columns and give the result 'OK' in the another column if there is match and give the result 'Not OK' if there is no match.

Screenshot:

[image: Capture]

The column KD Serial and D-Note number are the range of columns where barcode item scanned will be searched. Scanned D-Note has to be searched in the column D-Note Number and Scanned KD Serial no. has to searched in KD serial column. If both matches it should give result 
Ok' in status ok/ Not Ok column. All the items will be in scanned randomly and it should be searched randomly. I have tried using If condition and VLookUp but I need it to happen in backend when barcode scanning event happens.

I have used the below formula in the column Status OK/NOT OK column to search the match, but it is not working as expected.

```
=IF(AND(EXACT(I3,H3:H1048576), EXACT(J3, G3:G1048576)),"OK", "Not OK")
```

Note: D-Note Number can be repeated in column D-Note Number and Values in KD Serial column is unique. So if you see the image D-Note against KD-Serial will be repeated in column 'D-Note Number'. Barcode for the columns Scanned D-Note no and Scanned KD Serial no will scanned only once.

Comment: I suggest that you provide an example of the code you have already tried ([mcve]) and let us know if you have a specific problem. At the moment, I can't identify if you have an issue and your description is a little broad for us to understand what you want.

Comment: I have used this formula to match the condition, '=IF(AND(EXACT(I3,H3:H1048576), EXACT(J3, G3:G1048576)),"OK", "Not OK")' but it is not working exactly.

Answer (score 0):

to have "OK" only when both KD Serial and D-Note numbers are found **in the same row**, then place this in "K3":

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(J3,G:G,0)=MATCH(I3,H:H,0),"OK","Not OK),"Not OK")
```

while to have "OK" if both KD Serial and D-Note number are found regardless of the row they are found in, then place this in "K3":

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(J3,G:G,0)), ISNUMBER(MATCH(I3,H:H,0))),"OK","Not OK")
```

and then drag it down

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Idea but its not working as expected...when it goes to second row its not showing Not OK but the value is available in the search range.

Comment: is my code working for you? your example seem to show data starting at row 3

Comment: Could you let me know why you are using (MATCH(J3,G:G,0)=MATCH(I3,H:H,0)?

Comment: No it is not working, its showing Not OK in result... I just tested with values YL40G000C108B0D in cell I4 and 8A4023X001 in cell J4 but result is showing Not ok...

Comment: Now also the condition mismatches, user will scan a D-Note and KD Serial only once. For example user is scanning D-note YL40G000C108B0D it will have two KD - Serial scanned 8A4023X002 and 8A4023X001. So in I column one row of value and J column two row of values. So when it is matched two rows should OK status in result column K. 
.